# MPMoviePlayerController sometimes plays audio, not video when fading in

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I've got an issue where, in a UIScrollView I have a number of views (videocontrollers in the below) which act as pages for video content (initially a thumbnail view is shown).

Sometimes (but not always) when I scroll to the next page, the audio for the video starts playing but I get no visual. This doesn't seem to happen when I'm not fading the view in.

Video init code is:

```
  MPMoviePlayerController* moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

  self.moviePlayer = moviePlayer;

  [moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
  [moviePlayer setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeOne];
  [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

  moviePlayer.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
  moviePlayer.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[videoData.video src]];

  [self.videoController.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
  [self.videoController.view bringSubviewToFront:moviePlayer.view];
  [moviePlayer.view setAlpha:0.0f];

  // Movie Observer
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkMovieStatus:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];

  // Add tap handler
  UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onPlayerTapped:)];
  singleFingerTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
  singleFingerTap.delegate = self;
  [self.moviePlayer.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

  [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
```

And play code (to try to avoid black flash at the start of the video) is:

```
- (void)checkMovieStatus:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if(self.moviePlayer.readyForDisplay && (MPMovieLoadStatePlayable | MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK)) {

          [self.moviePlayer play];

          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];

          [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f animations:^{
              [self.moviePlayer.view setAlpha:1.0f];
          } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
              //[self.moviePlayer play]; // tried here as well
          }];
        }
}
```

Code to remove video view on scroll is:

```
- (void)removeMoviePlayer {
        if(self.moviePlayer) {
                [self.moviePlayer stop];

                [self.moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];

                self.moviePlayer = nil;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a rather strange fix to this problem. In my case I would swipe to the video and the audio would play and there would be no picture. If I swiped away and came back, everything worked fine so just for the fun of it I tried this

```
MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [self.arrayOfScrollView objectAtIndex:xx];
[mp play];
[mp stop];
[mp play];
```

Strangely that worked. Since you posted this six months ago, if you found another workaround, I'd love to know it.